# How do I make a command line argument into a vector with each character as a different value?

Tags: c++, vector, char, command-line-arguments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/*
void square(cLine, height){

}
*/
//void insertVector(vector<char> & cLine, )
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 5){
        cerr << "Incorrect number of arguments" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    ofstream writeFile(argv[4]);
    if (!writeFile.good()){
        cerr << "Bad file, could not open" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    int arrayLength = sizeof(argv[1]);
    vector<string> cLine;
    string cString(argv[1]);
    for(int i=0,i<arrayLength-2,++i){
        cLine.push_back(cString.substr(i,i+1));
    }
    cout << cLine << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to take an argument argv[1] and make it into a vector so I can easily splice it later on, I understand the argument is a c style char* array but I don't how to convert it into a vector where each index is exactly a character, yet is printable to console.

Comment: I think you meant `strlen` instead of `sizeof`

Comment: there is a constructor for `std::string` that does what you want.

Comment: `for(int i=0,i<arrayLength-2,++i){` --> `for(int i=0; i<arrayLength-2; ++i) {`

Comment: " make it into a vector so I can easily splice it later on" smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you think you can do with a vector that you cannot do with the  string you already have?

Comment: I most likely fell into the xy problem like you said, the main objective of the assignment is to make shapes out of a argument, hence the need for splicing. This is my first week using c++ and I'm not sure what to use to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration

```
int arrayLength = sizeof(argv[1]);
```

does not make sense because `sizeof(argv[1])` is equivalent to `sizeof( char * )` and does not yield the number of characters in the argument.

This statement

```
cout << cLine << endl;
```

also does not make sense because there is no overloaded `operator <<` for the template class `std::vector`.

Moreover this for loop

```
for(int i=0,i<arrayLength-2,++i){
```

is syntactically incorrect.

What you need is the following

```
#include <cstring>

//…

std::vector<char> cLine( argv[1], argv[1] + std::strlen( argv[1] ) );
for ( const auto &c : cLine ) std::cout << c;
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: It compiles correctly thank you, but I still get compilation errors when using cout <<

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what the for loop argument means? Also say I only wanted to print a range of the vector, ex. index 2-4, how would I go about that?

Comment: @WillWalters You can use just ( char c : cLine ). To output a range you can use an ordinary for loop as for example for ( std::vector<char>::size_type I = 2; I < 5; I++ ) std::cout << cLine[I];

Comment: Would it make sense to scrap using a vector and just use a string instead. Due to needing to concatenate, and using substr for index range selection?

Comment: @WillWalters Do as you like. If you need substrings then just create an object of the type std::string as already done in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could create `std::string`s (which are somewhat similar to `std::vector`s) out of the arguments. It'll make it easy to do what you'd like.

I'll refer to constructor numbers @ [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) 
and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int cppmain(std::string program, std::vector<std::string> args) {
    if(args.size() != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Incorrect number of arguments\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << program << " got arguments:\n";
    for(std::string& arg : args) {
        std::cout << " " << arg << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << program << " got arguments (alt. version):\n";

    for(size_t i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << " " << args[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "the first argument, char-by-char:\n";

    for(char ch : args[0]) {
        std::cout << ch << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "the first argument, char-by-char (alt. version):\n";

    for(size_t i = 0; i < args[0].size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << args[0][i] << '\n';
    }

    if(args[0].size() >= 6) {
        std::cout << "printing a range (start=2, length=4) of the first argument:\n";
        std::cout << args[0].substr(2, 4) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

// Let main() create a std::string out of the program name (argv[0]) using
// std::string constructor 5
//
// and a std::vector<std::string> out of the arguments using
// std::vector constructor 5 (iterators).
//
// {argv+1, argv+argc}  becomes arguments to the  args  parameter in cppmain()
//
// argv+1    points at the first program argument argv[1] (the begin iterator)
// argv+argc points one step beyond the last program argument (the end iterator)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain(argv[0], {argv + 1, argv + argc});
}
```

Comment: Is the parameters of the function making the set you placed inside the call into a vector of strings?

Comment: @WillWalters Updated the answer with some explanations.